# How to read the value from column

Tags: perl

Ineed to read the value of the column (First), the column is already seperated by tab from the below table. How can i do this in perl. Could someone help on this. Below is the table:

```
                                                         First    Available
JAB                       Result        Dat Con?         Con?     
--------                 ------        ---------------   -----   ---------
SLAL_DEPE                SUCCESS       No                Yes     No
```

Here the First Con is "Yes".. I want to read this value. Please share ur knowledge with me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @vals = split/\t+/;
    print $vals[3],"\n" if defined($vals[3]) && $vals[3] eq 'Yes';
}

__DATA__
                                                         First    Available
JAB                       Result        Dat Con?         Con?     
--------                 ------        ---------------   -----   ---------
SLAL_DEPE                SUCCESS       No                Yes     No
SLAL_DEPE                SUCCESS       No                No      No
```

**output:**

```
Yes
```

Comment: A potential problem with this solution is that it splits based on all white space.  The question specified that fields are delimited by tabs, so tabs should be used: `split /\t/`.  That way the code won't break if one of the fields contains a space.

Comment: @M42, If the First Con is No, would it still wrk?

Comment: @pauler: It'll print `Yes` if `First Con` contains `Yes` and nothing otherwise.

Comment: The value of FirstCon is no fixed. It may be yes or No also, in that case how will the value be fetched?

Comment: @pauler: You get the value in `$vals[3]`.

Comment: Actually i kee this data in a array, its a o/p of some cmd.. so its like @output = `$cmd`; and now how can i do while clause in array

Comment: @pauler: Change `while (<DATA>) {` into `foreach (@output) {`

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do it:

```
while (<>) {
    if (/^-+/) {
        $body = 1;
    } elsif ($body) {
        print ((split)[3])
    }
}
```